# jquery attr не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

```
var plans = {
  'plan1' : {
    Days: 80,
    percentPerDay: 0.02,
    minDeposit: 10,
    maxDeposit1: 99
  },
  'plan2' : {
    Days: 90,
    percentPerDay: 0.03,
    minDeposit: 100,
    maxDeposit1: 249
  },
  'plan3' : {
    Days: 100,
    percentPerDay: 0.035,
    minDeposit: 250,
    maxDeposit1: 499
  },
  'plan4' : {
    Days: 120,
    percentPerDay: 0.04,
    minDeposit: 500,
    maxDeposit1: 1000
  },
}

function setMinValue(plansArr, numberOfPlan) {
  var number = 'plan' + numberOfPlan;

  var plan = plansArr[number];
  console.log( plan.minDeposit); // 10
  var depositMin = $('#deposit').attr('min', plan.minDeposit);
  console.log( depositMin );
}

setMinValue(plans, 1);


            <div class="calc-center">
                <label for="select-plan">Выберите план</label>
                <select id="select-plan">
                    <option value="1">Crypt 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Crypt 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Crypt 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Crypt 4</option>
                </select>
                <label for="countday">Количество дней</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount_days" id="countday" readonly>
                <label for="deposit">Сумма депозита</label>
                <input type="number" name="deposit_amount" id="deposit" min="0" max="10000" step="1" autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Вы получите прибыль</legend>
                    <p>Дневная прибыль по тарифу</p>
                    <p><span id="profit-day">0.0000043000</span><span> $</span></p>
                    <p>Общая прибыль</p>
                    <p><span id="total-profit">0.0000043000</span><span> $</span></p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="/registration/" class="btn btn_invest">Инвестировать</a>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

Comment: где Ваш html? ()

Comment: @Igor думаю, это призыв импровизировать)

Comment: Почему вы решили что он не работает?

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вы перепутали геттер и сеттер. [`jQuery.attr(name, val)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) - это сеттер и он возвращает `jQuery` объект. Чтобы получить значение параметра необходимо вызывать этот метод с одним параметром [`jQuery.attr(name)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Answer (score 0):

В более новых Jquery рекомендуется использовать prop. а `attr(name, val);` это сеттер который устанавливает значение

```js
var plans = {
  'plan1': {
    Days: 80,
    percentPerDay: 0.02,
    minDeposit: 10,
    maxDeposit1: 99
  },
  'plan2': {
    Days: 90,
    percentPerDay: 0.03,
    minDeposit: 100,
    maxDeposit1: 249
  },
  'plan3': {
    Days: 100,
    percentPerDay: 0.035,
    minDeposit: 250,
    maxDeposit1: 499
  },
  'plan4': {
    Days: 120,
    percentPerDay: 0.04,
    minDeposit: 500,
    maxDeposit1: 1000
  },
}

function setMinValue(plansArr, numberOfPlan) {
  var number = 'plan' + numberOfPlan;

  var plan = plansArr[number];
  console.log(plan.minDeposit); // 10
  var depositMin = $('#deposit').prop('min');
  console.log(depositMin);
}

setMinValue(plans, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc-center">
  <label for="select-plan">Выберите план</label>
  <select id="select-plan">
                    <option value="1">Crypt 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Crypt 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Crypt 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Crypt 4</option>
                </select>
  <label for="countday">Количество дней</label>
  <input type="text" name="amount_days" id="countday" readonly>
  <label for="deposit">Сумма депозита</label>
  <input type="number" name="deposit_amount" id="deposit" min="0" max="10000" step="1" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Вы получите прибыль</legend>
    <p>Дневная прибыль по тарифу</p>
    <p><span id="profit-day">0.0000043000</span><span> $</span></p>
    <p>Общая прибыль</p>
    <p><span id="total-profit">0.0000043000</span><span> $</span></p>
    <p>
      <a href="/registration/" class="btn btn_invest">Инвестировать</a>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

надо так

`var depositMin = $('#deposit').attr('min');`